# PHP on apache server http calling javascript api on tomcat server

Tags: php, javascript, apache, tomcat

client <<====>>  apache http server(PHP) <<======>> Tomcat server( javascript api)

The client hits the PHP on apache http server, this intern should call a javascript api which returns a json object ,all the execution and loading should happen on apache http server and the client should not be involved once he/she has hit the PHP.

This runs fine if client directly calls the javascript on tomcat.

How can this be be done?
Will mod_jk connectors help in this?

client <<====>>  apache http server(PHP) <<======>> Tomcat server( javascript api)

Comment: Is your Javascript API a REST API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP-cURL to do a request to the Tomcat server from you php script: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Or, if you need something a bit simpler, just do file_get_contents to the http location: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/ ....... The image on this page shows the exact scenario of my problem.